# How does typescript decorators allow angular 2 to discover type metadata

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I don't understand how does typescript decorator `@Injectable` captures type information and how it later knows which constructor parameter corresponds to which type when no explicit `@Inject(...)` is provided within constructor parameter list? How to replicate such behavior and in simple terms create my own injector for my own library.

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
}

export class AppComponent {
    public constructor(private appService: AppService) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may see insight within the compiled code on how decorators works, for example

Compiled code looks something like below,

```
    ComponentClass = __decorate([
        core_1.Component({
            moduleId: module.id,
            selector: 'component-selector',
            templateUrl: 'component.html',
            styleUrls: ['component.css'],
            providers: [component_service_1.ComponentService]
        }), 
        __metadata('design:paramtypes', [component_service_1.ComponentService])
    ], ComponentClass);
```

when angular core looks into this it uses `Reflect.js` to get metadata info about component.

To create your own decorator, you can try below,

**MyCustomDecorator**

```
import "reflect-metadata";

interface ICustomDecoratorMeta{
    var1: string
}

export var MyCustomDecorator =
    (metadata: <ICustomDecoratorMeta>) => {
        return (target) => {
           Reflect.defineMetadata("MyCustomDecorator", metadata, target);
        }
    }
```

How to use it,

```
@MyCustomDecorator({
   var1 : "Hello"
})
export class MyClass(){}


// To retrieve metadata you can use below,

var metadata = Reflect.getMetadata('MyCustomDecorator', MyClass);
```

Hope this helps!!